# ¿Cómo desactivar varios campos en Javascript y jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

En la siguiente imagen aparece desactivado el campo **operación**. El código está hecho en *Javascript* y *jQuery*. ¿Cómo puedo desactivar los demás campos?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías mostrar algo de código? qué parte te está costando?

Answer (score 1):

Sería algo así, `input` es el nombre del control:

```
$("input").prop('disabled', true);
$("input").prop('disabled', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Disable #x
$( "#x" ).prop( "disabled", true );
 
// Enable #x
$( "#x" ).prop( "disabled", false );
```

para mas informacion : https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-disable-enable-a-form-element/

Aqui se encuentra una pregunta muy similar (esta en ingles):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577548/how-can-i-disable-a-button-in-a-jquery-dialog-from-a-function

Answer (score 0):

Para deshabilitar todos los elementos, de un formulario:

```
$("input, select, textarea").prop('disabled', true);
```